# Scrape dynamic contents using bs4

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

i'm scraping some information from mobile_comparison_website. but it's content are looking dynamic. I'm trying to scraping the dynamic content using selenium but its also does not given me expected output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
path = r'C:\\Users\\Goku\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get('https://versus.com/en')

res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

soup = bs(res, 'lxml')
box = soup.find('div', {'class':'CarouList__carouList___2WspW 
CarouList__isLandingPage___rPe4J'})

print(box)
```

[for example - i want to scrape all images inside the div and name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euumy.png)

Comment: What do you want from that url?

Comment: i want to scrape smartphone comparison data

Comment: Your question is REALLY broad... I want to scrape "some information" or "smartphone comparison data" isn't specific at all. You need to edit your question and limit it to the one thing you are trying to accomplish. First describe it with words so we understand the scenario. Then post the code you wrote attempting to complete the scenario. Since it's not working but we can't see it, you will need to post any error messages you are getting or a description of how the result isn't correct. You really should read [ask] carefully and use those tips to clarify your question also.

Answer (score 0):

You can find data within the html source code under the `<script>` tag. find that text, manipulate the string into a valid json format, then use `json.loads()` to read that in. Then you can have a look around that structure and pull out what you want. The url of the images are found there:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

my_url = 'https://versus.com/en'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
response = requests.get(my_url, headers=headers)

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(response.text, "html.parser")

scripts = page_soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
   if 'window.__data=' in script.text:
       jsonStr = script.text
       jsonStr = jsonStr.split('window.__data=')[-1]

       jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

phones = jsonData['landing']['trendings']['phone']['list']
for each in phones:
    root_url = 'https://versus.dadi.network'
    popImage = root_url + each['popImage']
    rivalImage = root_url + each['rivalImage']

    print ('%s\n%s' %(popImage, rivalImage))
```

**Output:**

```
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-a9-2018/front/front-1539337417084.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-a50/front/front-1551183669492.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-s10-plus/front/front-1550699605210.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/apple-iphone-xs-max/front/front-1536781345067.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-a50/front/front-1551183669492.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/huawei-p30-lite/front/front-1555000229505.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/xiaomi-redmi-note-7/front/front-1550507767671.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/xiaomi-mi-8-lite/front/front-1537824165879.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-s8/front/front-1490950798404.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-a50/front/front-1551183669492.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/huawei-p20-lite/front/front-1521538430205.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/huawei-p-smart-2019/front/front-1547733931933.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-a50/front/front-1551183669492.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-a30/front/front-1551187893794.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-m20/front/front-1550059143173.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-a30/front/front-1551187893794.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/oneplus-6t/front/front-1540985964061.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/google-pixel-3/front/front-1539114763774.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/samsung-galaxy-a40/front/front-1555086727000.variety.jpg
https://versus.dadi.network/huawei-p20-lite/front/front-1521538430205.variety.jpg
```

Comment: if the solution was what you needed, be sure to accept the solution above by clicking on the "check"